# If then with multiple expressions OCaml

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, ocaml

How can I code, in OCaml, something like this (main() in C)

```
for (i=0; i<y; i++)
    if (x==5)
    {
        y=i;
        return true;
    }
```

It would return the boolean True and y would be equal to the corresponding i value.

Basically, in OCaml, I was wondering if you could have a if like:

```
for i=0 to y-1 do
        if x=5 then
        begin 
            y=i
            true
        end
        else ()
done;;
```

I know the lines between begin-end aren't correctly implemented. I don't even know if what I want to do is possible in OCaml. If you are someone who has knowledge on this kindly share it with me. Thanks!

Comment: Your C code makes no sense. `x` doesn't change in the loop, so the condition is either always true or never true. You need to provide a bit more context.

Comment: Is `y` a local variable in your C code? If so, it is destroyed when the function returns, so the assignment is pointless.

Comment: I just want to be able to change a variable value and also return something in the same if-then in OCaml, instead of just returning

Comment: Can you show a complete example in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about early return from a for loop, this is how you'd it:

```
exception Break of int

let n =
  try
    for i = 0 to 5 do
      if i mod 2 = 0 then
        raise (Break i)
    done;
    0
  with
    Break i -> i
```

You could also assign to a `ref` cell instead of passing the value in the exception, if that fits your use case better. But this isn't the kind of code you should typically be writing in OCaml. Trying to emulate C in OCaml is almost always a bad idea.